# Squid Proxy Server not working ubuntu 12 04

Tags: 12.04, server, proxy, squid

long time ago while using ubuntu 10.04 i have install squid server and webmin and never check it. i know that webmin wont work for long time with ubuntu higher level so that why im back using 10.04 at that time. then i try to install ubuntu 12.04 by taking risk its ok without webmin as far squid still work .. i dont check it after install the 1st beta version of 12.04 and now .. i just wondering why it takes so long time to opening some games on fb or loading cnn news page then i try to check and restart also try to install it but i can't get the access to squid.

I try to go from directory

```
santos@santos:/etc$ cd squid
bash: cd: squid: No such file or directory
santos@santos:/etc$
```

here my screenshot 
[image]

how to have squid server for cache internet activity for ubuntu 12.04? are there any other option?

Answer (score 5):

It has been (re)named to `squid3`, so the config files are in `/etc/squid3/`.

You can start it with

```
service squid3 start
```